# Why does onClickListener for start, pause, stop buttons only need to be @override once?

Tags: java, android

I understand how to start, pause & stop a song, but why don't all onClickListener() need an @override?

I'm learning about MediaPlayer & AudioManager at the moment and would like to understand the reason for the layout on MainActivity.java below.

```
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.desiigner_panda);

    Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Play_Button);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I'm Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Pause_Button);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    });

    Button unMuteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Unmute_Button);
    unMuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1);
        }
    });

    Button MuteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Mute_Button);
    MuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No method *needs* `@Override`.

`@Override` is a hint to the compiler, indicating that you think that you are either overriding a method from a superclass or implementing a method from an interface. If you have `@Override`, and there is a mistake in your method signature (wrong parameters, wrong return type, etc.), the compiler can let you know about it.

You could remove `@Override` from the one method where it appears in your code listing, and your code would run just fine.

Having `@Override` is a good idea, to help catch bugs when you are writing your app, but it is not a requirement.